# Custom Column matching dates between range

Tags: m

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a custom column to match dates that fit between specific date ranges. I've tried using the below custom formula but doesn't seem to return anything

```
=if [#"Start Date (Calculated 2)"] <= #date(2019,09,01) and [#"Start Date (Calculated 2)"] < #date(2022,04,01) then "Yes" else [#"Start Date (Calculated 2)"]
```

However it doesn't match anything

Answer (score 0):

Mechanically, if your column is a date, your formula works fine except the logic makes no sense

You are looking for a date <01Sep2019 **and** <01Apr2022

You probably want to change it to this, replacing the first < with >

```
=if [#"Start Date (Calculated 2)"] >= #date(2019,09,01) and [#"Start Date (Calculated 2)"] < #date(2022,04,01) then "Yes" else [#"Start Date (Calculated 2)"]
```

Comment: does that answer your question?